# Base table or view not found laravel - Running scheduler cron

Tags: laravel, cron, shared-variable

while running `php artisan eventnotification:mail` in command, it throws below error
**"SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table "**

**My appserviceprovider.php**

```
public function boot() {
    $rolesList = $this->getRolesList();
    View::share("rolesListArr", $rolesList);
}
```

**My cron job:**

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->command('eventnotification:mail')->everyMinute();

}
```

How can i fix the " [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
  SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table "

Comment: are you creating notification?

Comment: for creating a notification you run this command ....php artisan make:notification email

Comment: yes that has been created.. while running "php artisan eventnotification:mail", it shows the error, which i have mentioned

Comment: i think there is no command like this. what do you want to achieve with this coammand?

Comment: i have created notification email, and i try to run in command prompt.

Comment: You can't run it in command prompt. check this how notication works. https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/notifications

Answer (score 0):

Check your migration file, maybe you are using `Schema::table`, like this:

```
Schema::table('table_name', function ($table)  {
    // ...
});
```

If you want to create a new table you must use `Schema::create:`

```
Schema::create('table_name', function ($table)  {
    // ...
});
```

See the [Laravel migration documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/migrations#creating-tables) for more information.

If you are using Schema::create then please provide the contents of your migration file.

Comment: thanks for your immediate response.. could you please elaborate your answer

Comment: for me , its was in the boot method of the app service provider as i set up a view::share() and i have already changed the database.